# Delphi offers import SDK file for PAServer, how do I create an SDK file?

Tags: macos, delphi, sdk

The latest Apple macOS SDK's are stored in folders, not a file, AFAICT..

So if I have an SDK on a macOS stored in a folder (inside xcode.app), how would i create an SDK "file"?

Delphi PAServer offers the ability to import an SDK "file" with sdk extension, not an SDK "folder" such as some.SDK/

Is an SDK "file" some sort of zip file, linked file, or special file that I could create that the PAServer import feature will accept as valid?

For people having issues with PAServer, this is required knowledge as some SDK's may not work with delphi compilers due to strange internal errors of dcc, so in emergency, switching to a specific SDK version can fix it.

Comment: "The latest Apple macOS SDK's are stored in folders, not a file, AFAICT." They've been in folders for some time. "For people having issues with PAServer, this is required knowledge as some SDK's may not work with delphi compilers due to strange internal errors of dcc, so in emergency, switching to a specific SDK version can fix it". Please indicate what error(s), if any.

Comment: the error is in Delphi Seattle, which uses an older version of PAServer, [dccosx Fatal Error] F2084 Internal Error: AV0AAF8A53-R00000014-0

Comment: Without the source for such an error, it's hard to tell what the problem is. Also, what version of Xcode?

Comment: The source, is a hello world blank application, nothing else. The sdk version is 10.13.1  downloaded with the latest xcode...I would have to check what the xcode version is if it is a different than the SDK number provided

Comment: Xcode and SDK numbers are not the same. I mean the version of Xcode when you click Xcode|About Xcode on the Mac